# deleting objects, going from ListView to DeleteView

Tags: django, django-views

I have a ListView and from this I want to delete some objects using DeleteView.  What I have so far:

views.py

```
class BlockListView(ListView):
    model= Classroom

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlockListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        classroom_blocks = Classroom.objects.all()
        context = {'classroom_blocks': classroom_blocks}
        return context

list_classroom_view = BlockListView.as_view()

class BlockDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Classroom
    success_url = reverse_lazy('classroom:blocklist')

delete_classroom_view = BlockDeleteView.as_view()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path('submitted', views.submitted, name='submitted'),
    path('classup/', create_classroom_view, name='classroom'),
    path('block/', views.block, name='block'),
    path('blocklist/', list_classroom_view, name='blocklist'),
    path(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/blockDelete/$', delete_classroom_view, name='blockDelete'),
]
```

template for listview:

```
{% for block in classroom_blocks %}
    <li>{{ block.get_course_block_display }}<a href ="{% url 'classroom:blockDelete' block.id %}" class="button" style="color:#999999">DELETE</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No classes set up yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
```

template for confirm delete:

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Confirm Delete</h1>
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object.course_block }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After I click the delete button from the listview, the url generated is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/classroom/%5E(%3FP89%5Cd+)/blockDelete/$` and this directs to the confirm delete page.  After confirming delete, I get a 404 error with `Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/classroom/%5E(%3FP89%5Cd+)/blockDelete/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `path()`, so you shouldn't be using regexes. Change the first and last URL patterns to:

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
...
path('<int:pk>/blockDelete/', delete_classroom_view, name='blockDelete'),
```

Now, when you click on the delete button from the list view, you should be taken to a url like `/classroom/1/blockDelete/`, and you shouldn't get a 404 when you submit the form.